# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

Tags: python, http, flask, server, python-requests

Im trying to make a local frontend flask server send a POST request to my local backend server. Both servers are running on python and on the same IP and network with different ports. The backend uses the http library.

I want to send a POST request from my frontend to my backend and then the backend to retunt status code 200.But i get this error!

Here is my frontend code:

```
from flask import *
import requests

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 7000

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/login_submit", methods=["POST"])
def login_submit():

    response = send_credentials_to_backend()
    if response == 200:
        return redirect(url_for('main'))
    else:
        return "Error: Failed to authenticate"


def send_credentials_to_backend():

    url = f"http://{HOST}:8000/login/submit"
    response = requests.post(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.status_code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT, debug=True)
```

Here is my backend:

```
from http.server import *
import json

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8000


class HTTPServerClient(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        print("Got request POST")
        if self.path.endswith('/login/submit'):
            self.send_response_only(200, message=None)

    def do_GET(self):
        print("Got request GET")
        self.send_response_only(200, message=None)
        print(self.client_address)


server = HTTPServer((HOST, PORT), HTTPServerClient)

print("Back-End running...")

server.serve_forever()
server.server_close()
```

Here is my log:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
response = self._make_request(
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
response = conn.getresponse()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 454, in getresponse
httplib_response = super().getresponse()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1377, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 320, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 289, in _read_status
raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 470, in increment
raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\util.py", line 38, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
response = self._make_request(
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
response = conn.getresponse()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 454, in getresponse
httplib_response = super().getresponse()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1377, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 320, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 289, in _read_status
raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2213, in **call**
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\front-end\app.py", line 23, in login_submit
response = send_credentials_to_backend()
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\front-end\app.py", line 33, in send_credentials_to_backend
response = requests.post(url)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Monkata\Documents\PyCharm Projects\TEST WORKING SITE\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

I set the message=None in the backend when it returns 200 but that din't work.
I tried with both POST and GET requests. That din't work.
I removed any paylod when sending the request. Also din't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
 self.send_response(200)
 self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
 self.end_headers()
```

Instead of this:

```
self.send_response(200, message=None)
```

In the backend!